# Stack overflow error with Symbolic C++

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, symbolic-math

The simplest version of the problem is this:

```
Symbolic x("x");
Symbolic y("y");
Symbolic a("a");
Symbolic ans;
a = 1.1;
ans = a ^ (x + y);
std::cout << ans;
```

Basically this begins an infinite recursion cycle and leads to a stack overflow.

If a = 0 or a = 1 the stack overflow does not happen because 0^x = 0 and 1^x = 1. If a is not set to a constant value it will print "a^(x+y)" because that cannot be simplified. Making a an integer (other than 1 and 0) does not change anything.

Optimally this would print "(1.1)^(x+y)" because there is no way to simplify that.

I am wondering if anyone has had this problem before or knows  work around. I tried googling but this website has made it impossible to find information on Stack Overflow errors using google.